# Generating a CCDF plot for a list of data

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, cdf

I am trying to plot a CCDF graph using scipy and matplot but for some reason it is not graphing. I based my code from the following source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-calculate-and-plot-a-cumulative-distribution-function-with-matplotlib-in-python/. However, it does not seem to work. Take a look at my code and let me know if you see anything that I don't.

```
# compare the completion times and service times and check that they are different
# do this for multiple runs 
# 

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

class Job:
    def __init__(self, arrivalTime, size):
        self.arrivalTime = arrivalTime
        self.size = size
        self.departureTime = None

departures = 0
maxDepartures = 100000

# Function that generates the job size
def generateJobSize():
    return np.random.exponential(1 / 3)

# Function that generates an interarrival time
def generateInterarrivalTime():
    return np.random.exponential(1 / 2)

jobQueue = [] 
serverEmpty = True
nextArrTime = generateInterarrivalTime()
nextDepTime = float('inf')
completionTimes = []
# initiate pointer for the job currently being serviced
servingJob = None
clock = 0.0
loop = 0

def handleArr():
  # declare these variables as global so that they can be edited outside the function
  global job, serverEmpty, servingJob, nextArrTime, nextDepTime, completionTimes
  # generate the size of the job
  size = generateJobSize()
  # create job object with those attriubtes
  job = Job(arrivalTime = clock, size = size)
  # if the server is empty upon this job's arrival into the system, immediately start servicing it 
  if serverEmpty == True:
    # create pointer that points to the job that is currently being serviced
    servingJob = job
    # determine the job's departure time based on the size and the current time
    job.departureTime = clock + job.size
    nextDepTime = job.departureTime
    # update the status of the server to busy
    serverEmpty = False
  else:
    # if a job is already being serviced, append the new arrival to the queue
    jobQueue.append(job)
  # generate the arrival time of the next job
  interArrTime = generateInterarrivalTime ()
  # set the next arrival time based upon that
  nextArrTime = clock + interArrTime
 
 

# fcn to handle departures
def handleDep():
  global job, departures, serverEmpty, servingJob, nextDepTime, completionTimes
  # determine the job's departure time based on the size and the current time
  job.departureTime = clock + job.size
  completionTimes.append(job.departureTime - job.arrivalTime)
  # update the time of the next departure based on this new information
  nextDepTime = clock + job.size
# when all the jobs have finished
# inc the counter by 1
  departures += 1
  # if the queue is not empty, pop the next job in line
  if len(jobQueue) != 0:
    job = jobQueue.pop(0)
    servingJob = job
  else: 
    serverEmpty = True
    nextDepTime = float("inf")
    servingJob = None

while departures < maxDepartures: 
  # determine the next event
  if nextArrTime <= nextDepTime:
    clock = nextArrTime
    handleArr()
  else: 
    loop += 1
    clock = nextDepTime
    handleDep()

print(len(completionTimes))

# --------- GRAPHS A CCDF PLOT -----------------

# # Sort completion times in ascending order
# completionTimes.sort()

# # Calculate probabilities for completion times
# probabilities_completion = np.arange(1, len(completionTimes) + 1) / len(completionTimes)

# # Calculate the CCDF for completion times
# ccdf_completion = 1 - probabilities_completion

# # Interpolate the data for a smooth line
# interp_func_completion = interp1d(completionTimes, ccdf_completion, kind='linear')

# # Generate interpolated data points for completion times
# completion_times_interp = np.linspace(min(completionTimes), max(completionTimes), num=1000)
# ccdf_completion_interp = interp_func_completion(completion_times_interp)

# # Plot completion times vs CCDF
# plt.plot(completion_times_interp, ccdf_completion_interp)
# plt.xlabel('Completion Time')
# plt.ylabel('CCDF')
# plt.title('Completion Time vs CCDF')
# plt.grid(True)
# plt.show()

x = np.sort(completionTimes)

#calculate CDF values
y = 1. * np.arange(len(completionTimes)) / (len(completionTimes) - 1)

#plot CDF
plt.plot(x, y)
```

I tried to plot the graph with the above commented code. It worked in the sense that the graph was generated, but I am not sure if it's actually correct.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your question seems to be unrelated to simulation. If you’re not even sure whether your CCDF code is correct, you should check it with known test cases rather than generating artificial data with an unknown distribution. As per the site guidelines, whittle your problem down to its core in the form of a minimal reproducible example.